# 4-layer PCB with VCC and GND inner planes with high current

Tags: relay, high-voltage, high-current, multi-layer

I have a 4-layer PCB with GND and power planes and on the top and bottom layers I have 220 VAC with 10 A currents. I have many questions about every part of this board but the most important ones are:

1. Is there going to be a problem with this kind of stack up? (signal <included 220 VAC> - power plane - GND plane-signal <included 220 VAC>)
2. Should I give a margin with good clearance between AC TH connector pins and the inner power planes?
3. What is a good clearance between AC tracks considering the current (10 A)?
4. What is a good track width for 220 V AC with 10 A current?
5. What is a good clearance between AC components and tracks and the low-voltage DC ones?

Comment: Why do you need a power plane on L3?

Comment: 1. Stackup generally ok gnd is generally on 2 and power on 3 for anything with high speed edges, 2 - use the same keepout for inner and outer tracks near 220v, 3 - depends, 4 - depends on laminate, copper weight and allowable temp rise in the tracks, 5 - depends...

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps a translation issue but we usually talk about minimum required instead of _”good”_ clearance. 3. Will only depend on voltage, not current. 4. Opposite, only depends on current and not voltage.

Comment: I would tend to disagree with Dean Franks. I can think of only one reason to make L3 in a 4-layer board a power plane, and that is *not* fast edges. Namely, if you need said power rail at many Amps of current in many places of the board at **low frequency**. If you want to draw any high frequency current from that power plane at low impedance, it *must* be in close proximity to a GND plane (and L2 + L3 are often not in close proximity).

Comment: @DeanFranks thank you for ur answers. For number 3 to 5 that needs more details: voltage is continuously 220 to 230v AC and the thickness of tracks are 35uM and temp rise is about 30°c in normal circumstances.

Comment: @tobalt 1 of Layers is for VCC and one of them is a ground plane

Comment: @winny voltage is 220v AC continuously and the current MIN   is 5 Amps and Max 10Amps if it helps to give me a better answer tnx

Comment: Check out http://www.creepage.com/. Be aware of your overvoltage category.

Comment: @winny tnx it does really help me